# The AVFoundation method: try loadingRequest.persistentContentKey(fromKeyVendorResponse: responseData!, options: nil) returning exception. Why?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

Why am I getting this exception while calling a method:

```
try loadingRequest.persistentContentKey(fromKeyVendorResponse: responseData!, options: nil)
```

I am trying to play a fairplay stream in offline mode. And it's working perfect in online mode, but not for offline.

Exception:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11835 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This content is not authorized., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x280fbca50 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-42681 "(null)"}}

Comment: Any solution for this?